# HTTP library for PHP (probably not Guzzle)

Tags: php, curl, composer-php, guzzle

I am developing a client library to be used amongst several internal projects.

Project A uses Guzzle 5.x
Project B uses Guzzle 6.x

Both are fairly monolithic and the likelihood of my migrating Project A over to 6.x is very slim.

The client library I'm developing uses Guzzle (5.x currently), and this library will be included in both Project A & B. However, Composer balks at this because I can't use Guzzle 5.x in my client lib and 6.x in the outer project (the project requiring the lib).

If there is any way to resolve this, I would greatly appreciate the advice (I suppose I could stick the Guzzle 5.x PHAR file in my client lib, but that feels dirty to me).

Now that that initial throat-clearing is done - and given that the above is resulting in an impasse for me, which HTTP lib would you recommend *besides* Guzzle?

1. **Requests** (http://requests.ryanmccue.info/) - my hesitation with this one is that it seems like a ground-up reimplementation of cURL, which a) seems unnecessary and b) seems doomed to playing catchup with cURL and the complexity of HTTP coming with HTTP2 etc; seems like this will be a headache to maintain
2. **HTTPFul** (https://github.com/nategood/httpful) - doesn't seem actively developed anymore
3. **Buzz** (https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz) - doesn't seem actively developed anymore

---

... or

---

4. stop being full of ******, keep your current library code working and just include the damn **Guzzle 5.x PHAR**.

Comment: I don't think #4 really is an option. Assuming your project is using composer's autoloader, you'll get namespace collisions trying to include the 5.x phar alongside the installed 6.x (error attempting to redefine class). No?

Comment: Shit, I think you're right. I could maybe require it under a different PSR-4 definition...?

Comment: If you want a lightweight HTTP client that uses curl, http://unirest.io/php.html might be worth a look. I haven't used it, but Mashape is a well known entity. Seems active. I'd probably use that or Requests, and avoid the guzzle conflict personally. Stinks, I know.

Comment: I was in the exact same position a few months ago, and we made the painful decision to upgrade all our projects to guzzle 6.x. Had we not been able to do that, I think I would have just used Requests or Unirest.

Comment: What a legend. This looks like the perfect combo of sane (i.e. using cURL) and active (loads of downloads, recent commits) - cheers mate! I'll give this a go

Comment: Please add that as an answer and i'll upvote it once I give this a proper shake

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: @JayBlanchard agreed, but I do have a bona-fide question in the first section which could be answered objectively, but yeah the second part is a bit more subjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Running Guzzle 5 alongside 6

I don't think loading Guzzle 5.x alongside Guzzle 6 is an option, even using Phar. You'll likely hit namespace collisions, assuming you're using Composer's autoloader.

### Alternative HTTP client libraries

I've heard good things about Requests, but haven't used it myself. I understand your concerns about reinventing the wheel.

If you want a lightweight HTTP client that uses curl, take a look at http://unirest.io/php.html. I haven't used it, but Mashape is a well known entity. Seems active.

### Use the HTTPPlug adapter

This is also worth a look:

http://httplug.io/

Now your individual projects can wire up Guzzle 6 or Guzzle 5 to this adapter, and you can code your library against a single PSR-7 API.

Comment: Unfortunately HTTPlug isn't going to work - but Unirest is perfect